# Terraform - transform list of lists to into a new list of lists

Tags: list, terraform, transform, hcl

In Terraform, I need to transform my input data structure from e.g.:

```
vip_lists = [
    ["1.0.1.1", "1.0.1.2", "1.0.1.3", "1.0.1.4"]
    ["1.0.2.1", "1.0.2.2", "1.0.2.3", "1.0.2.4"]
    ["1.0.0.1", "1.0.0.2", "1.0.0.3", "1.0.0.4"]
]
```

to produce an output like this:

```
vip_sets = [
    ["1.0.1.1", "1.0.2.1", "1.0.0.1"]
    ["1.0.1.2", "1.0.2.2", "1.0.0.2"]
    ["1.0.1.3", "1.0.2.3", "1.0.0.3"]
    ["1.0.1.4", "1.0.2.4", "1.0.0.4"]
]
```

So essentially, i need to take my input list of lists and create an output which is again a list of lists but whose 0th list is a list of the 0th elements from each of the lists in the input...then the same again for the 1st and so on.
I can't know in advance how many lists will be in the input or how long they will be, but we can assume the lists will all be the same length if that helps.

I've tried pretty much everything I can think of and searched the web but since with no luck. All suggestions would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of horrible, but it works (Although I haven't tested what it'd do if `vip_lists` was empty. Probably crash, as I'm indexing to `vip_lists[0]` without checking):

```
locals {
  vip_lists = [
    ["1.0.1.1", "1.0.1.2", "1.0.1.3", "1.0.1.4"],
    ["1.0.2.1", "1.0.2.2", "1.0.2.3", "1.0.2.4"],
    ["1.0.0.1", "1.0.0.2", "1.0.0.3", "1.0.0.4"]
  ]

  vip_sets = [for i in range(0, length(local.vip_lists[0])): [for j in range(0, length(local.vip_lists)): local.vip_lists[j][i]]]
}

output "vip_sets" {
  value = local.vip_sets
}
```

```
$ terraform apply
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

vip_sets = [
  [
    "1.0.1.1",
    "1.0.2.1",
    "1.0.0.1",
  ],
  [
    "1.0.1.2",
    "1.0.2.2",
    "1.0.0.2",
  ],
  [
    "1.0.1.3",
    "1.0.2.3",
    "1.0.0.3",
  ],
  [
    "1.0.1.4",
    "1.0.2.4",
    "1.0.0.4",
  ],
]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much @carr0t, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

I once wrote version of this for lists of lists that are not the same length for one of our modules on [github.com/mineiros-io](https://github.com/mineiros-io) where we used such transformations to create 2 dimensional sets of resources using `count`. (Those are not in use atm as we transformed them to maps for use with ressource level `for_each`).

```
locals {
  matrix = [
    ["1.0.1.1", "1.0.1.4"],
    ["1.0.2.1", "1.0.2.2", "1.0.2.3", "1.0.2.4"],
    ["1.0.0.1", "1.0.0.3", "1.0.0.4"]
  ]

  row_lengths = [
    for row in local.matrix : length(row)
  ]

  max_row_length = max(0, local.row_lengths...)

  output = [
    for i in range(0, local.max_row_length) : [
      for j, _ in local.matrix : try(local.matrix[j][i], null)
    ]
  ]

  output_compact = [
    for i in range(0, local.max_row_length) : compact([
      for j, _ in local.matrix : try(local.matrix[j][i], null)
    ])
  ]
}

output "matrix" {
  value = local.output
}

output "compact" {
  value = local.output_compact
}
```

which can handle dynamic list sizes and output them compact or filled with `null` values:

```
Outputs:

compact = [
  [ "1.0.1.1", "1.0.2.1", "1.0.0.1" ],
  [ "1.0.1.4", "1.0.2.2", "1.0.0.3" ],
  [ "1.0.2.3", "1.0.0.4" ],
  [ "1.0.2.4" ],
]

matrix = [
  [ "1.0.1.1", "1.0.2.1", "1.0.0.1" ],
  [ "1.0.1.4", "1.0.2.2", "1.0.0.3" ],
  [ null,      "1.0.2.3", "1.0.0.4" ],
  [ null,      "1.0.2.4", null      ],
]
```

I know an answer is already accepted, but maybe some one can still make use of this dynamic version.